# Android selinux Customization under Android P

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I'd like to add a module which could be something like /system/bin/mymodule
and surely I need customization sepolicy for this with defining its context and write the policy

And I know since Android 8 it brings Treble with [limitations](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/implement#key_files) and I likely just modify the sepolicy under **device/manufacturer/device-name/sepolicy** which I could add mymodule.te file and maybe something like

```
type mymodule, domain;
type mymodule_exec, exec_type, file_type;
init_daemon_domain(mymodule)
```

But in my situation, it may break the neverallow sepolicy under system/sepolicy/private/domain.te , So maybe I need modify it with something **neverallow { -mymodule }**

But in my concern this may violate the android treble thing, And maybe make fails to pass the CTS?

So the question is Was my concern right? And if it right Is there some other way I could pass this neverallow sepolicy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`system/sepolicy/public/attributes`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/heads/master/public/attributes) defines many `domain`s for different usage, such as `appdomain` for normal apps, `netdomain` for apps need network access, and etc. Maybe you should change the correct `domain` for your module, based on your module's operation. In many cases, it will satisfy your demand.

Comment: Surely not break neverallow and define other domain is a way, But for now, type xx domain just suits me, maybe I need to dive into what type domain really defines and thinking of the way, Anyway thx for the insight :)